# pygtk not working on windows even after installation

Tags: python, windows, gtk

I have installed pygtk in windows from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/) . Still, when i run a code that has the statement `import gtk` in it, i get the error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pycalc\calc2.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

I got the message that "pygtk is installed in your machine", after the installation completion. Please help me

Comment: Make sure 'gtk' module is in your Python PATH.Checking yout python PATH by using `sys.path`.

Comment: @LiuLang: How to add it to the path?

Comment: I have no Windows system, but I googled and found some answers, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7